# Merge particular part of JSON together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to merge particular part of a JSON code with another JSON. To clarify, please refer to example below:

JSON 1:

```
{"metadata": {
    "userName": "Batman",
    "userId" : "402",
    "config":{
        "a" : "some text here",
        "b" : "some other text here"
    }
}}
```

JSON 2:

```
{"metadata": {
    "userName": "Superman",
    "userId" : "102",
    "config":{
        "a" : "Overwrite Text 1",
        "b" : "Overwrite Text 2"
    }
}}
```

Now, I want to overwrite ONLY `config` part JSON 1 with JSON 2 So that JSON 1 will become:

```
{"metadata": {
    "userName": "Batman",
    "userId" : "402",
    "config":{
        "a" : "Overwrite Text 1",
        "b" : "Overwrite Text 2"
    }
}}
```

I have already tried using loop but I want to figure out if there is more efficient way to code this up. I am using Angular and pure JS.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Object.assign   -  [Mozilla foundation doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);
var obj2 = JSON.parse(json2);
Object.assign(obj1.metadata.config,obj2.metadata.config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its really simple:

```
json1.metadata.config = json2.metadata.config;
```

You overwrite its `config` data with the config from the other json object.

Let me know if you want me to elaborate more.

Comment: When you're editing finalJSON you are also editing json1.

Comment: My bad. I was trying to make it really obvious what was happening, but in doing so probably overcomplicated it. It all still worked as expected by the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
json1.metadata.config = json2.metadata.config;
```

should be enough.

You've got to remember that modifiying json2.metadata.config will modify json1.metadata.config, this is a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as Djave said is correct, but if you're not using ES6 and a transpiler you can take advantage of Angular itself and do a plain [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);
var obj2 = JSON.parse(json2);
obj1.metadata.config = angular.copy(obj2.metadata.config);
```

This way you will get the new JSON part copied and referenced on its own.